# Find a particular list inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I got two different lists (let's call them A and B) of lists and I have to find the elements that are in B and not in A and viceversa. The lists inside the two main lists can be unordered and they basically contains strings. I'm looking for a code or an hint to solve this problem.

EDIT: I didn't post the code because it was a lot stupid. However as requested, the code I tried:

```
for elem in list0:
    if not (elem in list1):
        for d in list1:
           if not (d in list0):
               /*stuff I got to do on the elements*/
```

EDIT2: test case:

```
A = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
B = [[b, a, c], [a, o, p]]
```

I want to exec funct(A, B) and get as return value C = [[a, o, p]]. I also need the viceversa, D = [d, e, f].

Comment: please post the code you tried, and/or an example of the data you want to treat

Comment: So you want the unique sub-lists?

Comment: Yes, where elements in list have to be considered unordered.

Comment: Are the elements in the nested lists (a,b,p,etc) hashable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you input data is list of list of strings then you can use something like this:

```
diff = lambda a,b: [x for x in a if x not in b]

mergelist = lambda lVals: reduce(lambda res,x: res + x, map(tuple, lVals))

diff(mergelist(A), mergelist(B))
diff(mergelist(B), mergelist(A))
```

EDITED as per comment:

```
mergelist = lambda lVals: reduce(lambda res,x: res + x, map(tuple, lVals))
diff = set(a) ^ set(b) # would contains difference between two initial lists
```

EDITED:

```
A = [['a', 'b','c'], ['d','e', 'f']]
B = [['b', 'a', 'c'], ['a', 'o', 'p']]

diff = lambda a,b: [list(x) for x in map(tuple, map(sorted, a)) if x not in map(tuple, map(sorted, b))]
print diff(A, B)
print diff(B, A)
```

Comment: I've removed mine. But yes would need to convert parameters to tuples.

Answer (score 1):

If your two lists are l1 and l2:

```
set(l1).symmetric_difference(set(l2))
```

or

```
set(l1) - set(l2)
```

depending on what you need.

Which *won't* work because lists aren't hashable... If the elements inside the lists are hashable then use the following:

```
[list(x) for x in set([frozenset(x) for x in l1]) ^ set([frozenset(x) for x in l2])]
```

Note: this won't return the original elements, reorders the lists.

Comment: the first one should be set(l1) ^ set(l2) ;)

Comment: Turning the lists into sets as shown doesn't work because the nested lists in the OP's question aren't hashable.

Comment: THX, fixed it, doesn't look so nice anymore:)

Comment: @yLH: Not sure how to apply your update to the question -- it results in `[[b, a, c], [a, b, c], [d, e, f], [a, o, p]]` regardless of whether `l1` and `l2` are `A` and `B` or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If everything in your lists and sublists are hashable, the following would work and be relatively fast since `set` membership testing and differences are generally O(1).

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,o,p = 'a','b','c','d','e','f','o','p' # make these hashable things

A = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
B = [[b, a, c], [a, o, p]]

def is_iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return not isinstance(obj, basestring) # consider strings atomic

def flatten(seq):
    for item in seq:
        if is_iterable(item):
            for subitem in flatten(item):
                yield subitem
        else:
            yield item

print list( set(flatten(A)) - set(flatten(B)) )
print list( set(flatten(B)) - set(flatten(A)) )
```

Output:

```
['e', 'd', 'f']
['p', 'o']
```